# Adding to the classpath on OSX

Tags: java, classpath

Can anyone tell me how to add to the classpath on OSX?

Comment: Do you want to fix a single application, a lot of applications for a single user or a lot of application for all users on the machine?

Comment: javac -cp .:/home/ec2-user/lib/*: QuickStart.java

Answer (score 104, accepted):

If you want to make a certain set of JAR files (or .class files) available to every Java application on the machine, then your best bet is to add those files to `/Library/Java/Extensions`.

Or, if you want to do it for every Java application, but only when **your** Mac OS X account runs them, then use `~/Library/Java/Extensions` instead.

**EDIT:** If you want to do this only for a particular application, as Thorbjørn asked, then you will need to tell us more about how the application is packaged.

Comment: Saved my day for making JUnit work on Vim with Syntastic syntax checker plugin. I wonder why there wasn't any other simple installation example for this on the www...

Comment: Why MAC is not respecting -cp/-classpath options, looks like it always loads the jars from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

Comment: -jar command is able to scan /Library/Java/Extensions, ~/Library/Java/Extensions

Comment: This works great as a workaround, but I agree with @kanagavelu It would be good to know why classpath is being ignored.

Comment: I tried placing the jar files in the `Extensions` it does not work

Answer (score 46):

In OSX, you can set the classpath from scratch like this:

```
export CLASSPATH=/path/to/some.jar:/path/to/some/other.jar
```

Or you can add to the existing classpath like this:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/some.jar:/path/to/some/other.jar
```

This is answering your exact question, I'm not saying it's the right or wrong thing to do; I'll leave that for others to comment upon.

Comment: I just want to add my jar to classpath. Why are there paths to two jars?

Comment: He is showing how to add more than 1 jar. He also implies that adding just 1 jar is simply appending `:path/to/jar` to the existing classpath @cegprakash

Answer (score 9):

To specify a classpath for a single Java process, you can add a classpath option when you run the Java command.

In you command line. Use
`java -cp "path/to/your/jar:." main`
rather than just
`java main`

The option tells Java where to search for libraries.

Answer (score -1):

If your shell is tcsh or csh, you can set it in /etc/profile.  Open terminal, "vim /etc/profile" and add the following line:

`setenv CLASSPATH (insert your classpath here)`

Answer (score -8):

Normally there's no need for that. First of all

```
echo $CLASSPATH
```

If there's something in there, you probably want to check Applications -> Utilites -> Java.

Comment: Fixed it for them, to save the dogpiling of downvotes.

Comment: Returns me an empty row?

Comment: if the  CLASSPATH env var is not set in your shell you will get an empty row ... => if you want it to contain something you should set it in .bash_profile , .bashrc or whatever env vars source file your shell might use ...