# JBoss admin-console fails to load - missing Log4J jar?

Tags: jboss, log4j

I downloaded JBoss 5.1 and unzipped to

```
~/jboss/
```

such that JBoss is installed into:

```
~/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/
```

I run the default deployment by using the following command found in jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/bin

```
./run.sh -c default
```

While JBoss starts (http://127.0.0.1:8080/), admin-console is not deployed. The log file:

```
jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/log
```

shows the following information:

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfsfile:/Users/jackwootton/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/admin-console.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/Users/jackwootton/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/az6n6v-tjilfb-h32fokxn-1-h32fosuo-v/admin-console.war/ deployment failed
  Deployment "vfszip:/Users/jackwootton/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/quartz-ra.rar/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.
```

The Log4J jar file exists in:

```
jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/lib/jboss-logging-log4j.jar
```

I have three questions:

1. Have I understood the problem correctly (i.e. that admin-console cannot find the required Log4j JAR file and therefore is not deployed)?
2. What can I do to fix this problem?
3. Why would an out-of-the-box deployment have this problem in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was missing jars in the classpath. I added the following jar files (found in the lib directory of your JBoss installation) to my classpath:

```
concurrent.jar  getopt.jar  jaxb-impl.jar   log4j-boot.jar  trove.jar
dom4j.jar   javassist.jar   jaxb-xjc.jar    osgi.core.jar   wstx.jar
```

Since I'm using Mac OS X I followed [this StackOverflow post on adding jars to classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675765/adding-to-the-classpath-on-osx).

One tip: I initially added all the JBoss jars to my classpath (jboss-XXX.jar), but this results in JBoss looking in /Library/Java/Extensions for configuration files.