# Azure connect java Web App(java) to SQLDatabase

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, jdbc

tried in Azure to connect Web App - Java with SQL Database. 
I used this example and this page:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-java-simple-windows/

I copy paste my connection string and add my IP to SQL servers/mydatabase/settings/firewall settings

When I run it from Tomcat8(Eclipse) - locally, I get the bottom error.

I can connect with SQL Management Studio with User and Pass that I used in conn. string so access data should be right. 
I also add sqljdbc4.jar lib downloaded from link in article.

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://mydatabase.database.windows.net:1433;database=mydatabase;user=[Server admin]@mydatabase;password=[MyAdminPassword];encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
>       at customerwebservice.SQLDatabaseTest.getDatabase(SQLDatabaseTest.java:30)
>       at customerwebservice.GetCustomers.doGet(GetCustomers.java:34)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;

public class SQLDatabaseTest {

public String getDatabase(){

    String connectionString = "";

    connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://mydatabase.database.windows.net:1433;database=mydatabase;user=[Server admin]@mydatabase;password=[My Password];encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";

    // Declare the JDBC objects.
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    PreparedStatement prepsInsertPerson = null;
    PreparedStatement prepsUpdateAge = null;

    try {           
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);

        return "Connected";      
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        // Close the connections after the data has been handled.
        if (prepsInsertPerson != null) try { prepsInsertPerson.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
        if (prepsUpdateAge != null) try { prepsUpdateAge.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
        if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
    }

   return "Not Connected"; 


   }
}
```

**EDITED:**
I figured out what was wrong. Because I am using Mac I did not add sqljdbc42.jar file to the Classpath. In windows you just run .exe but on Mac you need to manually add it.

This answer helps me add it to Classpath: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676261/1436690

But now I have another problem, because I also need to add sqljdbc42.jar into Azure Web App classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. Because I am using Mac I did not add sqljdbc42.jar file to the Classpath. In windows you just run .exe but on Mac you need to manually add it.

This answer helps me add it to Classpath:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676261/1436690