# How do I add a permanent CLASSPATH to my Terminal on Mac OS El Capitan?

Tags: java, macos, apache, path, environment-variables

I want to add the java-servlet-api.jar to the classpath variable.

```
export CLASSPATH=/.../java-servlet-api.jar
```

adds the class path to only one session of the terminal. How do I permanently add this to CLASSPATH?

I looked at a few links which asked me to modify the bashrc file, but I am unable to locate it on EL Capitan. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding to the classpath on OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1676261/1248974)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding to the classpath on OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675765/adding-to-the-classpath-on-osx)

Comment: Mac OS doesn't automatically make those user config files like `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`, you have to manually create them - From a Terminal shell type `touch ~/.bashrc` then edit and add your `export`s lines. [How can I create bash_profile and bashrc](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219206). However, as Thomas Arnaud stated, and also in my experience, Mac doesn't do a good job detecting `.bashrc`  so I've added exports to `~/.bash_profile` and works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You choose 1 of 2 solutions below:

**Solution 1**:
Open Terminal, then type:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/file/java-servlet-api.jar
```

then:

```
source .bash_profile
```

**Solution 2**:
Open terminal, type command:

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

you will see something like this:

[image]

press <kbd>i</kbd>, add your file to classpath like sample.

then, press <kbd>esc</kbd>, type <kbd>:wq</kbd>, then <kbd>return</kbd>

Make effective: don't need restart, type:

```
source .bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, I am not sure that Mac OS terminal launches the `.bashrc` file.
But it launches the `.profile` for sure.

Open a new terminal and launch this command :

```
echo 'export CLASSPATH=/.../java-servlet-api.jar' >> $HOME/.profile
```

Then open a new terminal and your environment variable should be ok.