# Vertx failing to compile external libraries

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, compilation, vert.x

I am building a vertx server using IntelliJ as my IDE, and my project builds fine there. However, when I try to run my server from the terminal it fails due to the following compilation errors and am unsure why. It compiles and runs perfectly fine without the aws dependency from terminal, and I have tested internally to IntelliJ that the libraries are being detected. I would appreciate some help with this issue!

```
/ExampleProject/src/main/java/Server/Server.java:4: error: package com.amazonaws.auth.profile does not exist
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
                                 ^ 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed
    at io.vertx.core.impl.verticle.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:120)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:38)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.createVerticles(DeploymentManager.java:184)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeployVerticle$2(DeploymentManager.java:157)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.checkCallHandler(FutureImpl.java:158)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.setHandler(FutureImpl.java:100)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:130)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:102)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.deployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:90)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.deployVerticle(VertxImpl.java:574)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VertxIsolatedDeployer.deploy(VertxIsolatedDeployer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.ClasspathHandler.deploy(ClasspathHandler.java:160)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.RunCommand.deploy(RunCommand.java:389)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.RunCommand.run(RunCommand.java:262)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.execute(VertxCommandLauncher.java:230)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.dispatch(VertxCommandLauncher.java:365)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.dispatch(VertxCommandLauncher.java:328)
    at io.vertx.core.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed!
    at io.vertx.core.impl.verticle.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:117)
    ... 21 more
Failed in deploying verticle 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed
    at io.vertx.core.impl.verticle.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:120)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:38)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.createVerticles(DeploymentManager.java:184)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeployVerticle$2(DeploymentManager.java:157)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.checkCallHandler(FutureImpl.java:158)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.setHandler(FutureImpl.java:100)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:130)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:102)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.deployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:90)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.deployVerticle(VertxImpl.java:574)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VertxIsolatedDeployer.deploy(VertxIsolatedDeployer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.ClasspathHandler.deploy(ClasspathHandler.java:160)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.RunCommand.deploy(RunCommand.java:389)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.RunCommand.run(RunCommand.java:262)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.execute(VertxCommandLauncher.java:230)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.dispatch(VertxCommandLauncher.java:365)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.dispatch(VertxCommandLauncher.java:328)
    at io.vertx.core.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed!
    at io.vertx.core.impl.verticle.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:117)
    ... 21 more

java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed
    at io.vertx.core.impl.verticle.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:120)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:38)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.createVerticles(DeploymentManager.java:184)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeployVerticle$2(DeploymentManager.java:157)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.checkCallHandler(FutureImpl.java:158)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.setHandler(FutureImpl.java:100)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:130)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:102)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.deployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:90)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.deployVerticle(VertxImpl.java:574)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VertxIsolatedDeployer.deploy(VertxIsolatedDeployer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.ClasspathHandler.deploy(ClasspathHandler.java:160)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.RunCommand.deploy(RunCommand.java:389)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.RunCommand.run(RunCommand.java:262)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.execute(VertxCommandLauncher.java:230)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.dispatch(VertxCommandLauncher.java:365)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.VertxCommandLauncher.dispatch(VertxCommandLauncher.java:328)
    at io.vertx.core.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed!
    at io.vertx.core.impl.verticle.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:117)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Make sure you have `com.amazonaws` dependencies in your pom.xml. Do a refresh of project, clean build again and try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the .jar files to the classpath. This post was helpful for me: [Adding to the classpath on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675765/adding-to-the-classpath-on-osx)