# How to run JTS Testbuilder in Mac?

Tags: jts

According to the user guide, Mac users can run JTS Testbuilder following these instructions

> Add to the class path: jdom.jar, xerces.jar, jts.jar, jts_test.jar (these
> files are supplied with JTS)

> Execute at a command prompt:
> java com.vividsolutions.jtstest.testbuilder.JTSTest

I have added the .jar files to `/Library/Java/Extensions`, as suggested in [Adding to the classpath on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675765/adding-to-the-classpath-on-osx), and that would solve the first part, but when trying to execute the second sentence, it returns

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.vividsolutions.jtstest.testbuilder.JTSTest
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vividsolutions.jtstest.testbuilder.JTSTest
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run JTS Testbuilder in Mac:

1. add the provided .jar files to /Library/Java/Extensions or wherever you have the classpath.
2. in the Terminal prompt, type `cd path/to/the/jts/bin_folder`
3. type `bash testbuilder.sh`